# Trying to use closeonoid to update tortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, exe

So have been trying to automatically update SVN using this code/.exe:

@echo off

"C:\Progrm Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe" /command:update /path:"C:/SVN/Company/Products" /closeoned:2

Unfortunately I keep getting this error message:
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe-updateSVN.exe
The NTVDM CPU has encountered an illegal instruction.
CS:1210 IP:0101 OP:65 63 68 6f 20 Choose 'Close' to terminate the application.

As far as I can tell this should be fairly basic, does any one know how to remedy this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start from fixing typos in syntax

> To close the progress dialog at the end of a command automatically without using the permanent setting you can pass the **/closeonend** parameter.

In order to remedy situation just use command-line lient for updating Working Copy (it can be installed with TortoiseSVN 1.7.* from TSVN-installer or separately)

Answer (score 1):

Ahem:

> C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe-updateSVN.exe

you realize that neither TortoiseSVN nor any 'clean' Subversion client installs anything with that name, and especially not in the `system32` directory?

I would first analyze that exe file with one or two virus scanners, and then get rid of it.

Because the error `The NTVDM CPU has encountered an illegal instruction` means that some 16-bit code failed to run - and Subversion and TortoiseSVN both are either plain 32-bit or even 64-bit applications with **absolutely no 16-bit code**.

That really indicates that you've got a problem with your system, not with the command you're trying to run or with the options you're passing.